# Apache Camel how to create route with 2 different Google pubsubs

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

When building a route I want to pull a message from one google pubsub and send it to another. In other words in my RouteBuilder I want:

```
from(<pubsub1>)
 .to(<pubsub2>);
```

To authenticate I have 2 JSON keyfiles. If I was going to use just one pubsub topic I would authenticate like this:

```
GooglePubsubConnectionFactory cF = new GooglePubsubConnectionFactory ();
cF.setCredentialsFileLocation(<file location>);
GooglePubsubComponent pubsub = getContext().getComponent("google-pubsub");
pubsub.setConnectionFactory(cF);
```

But I have two pubsubs with different keys. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should supply a serviceAccountKey parameter in the endpoint URI, e.g.

```
from("google-pubsub://project-id:destinationName?serviceAccountKey=/path/to/key/file")
  .to(...)
```

Then you can connect to different topics using different service accounts.

It looks like this was fixed between versions 3.7 and 3.11. Prior to 3.11 it seems you could only connect using one google service account. In this case you could update the access control for those topics so that the service account has access to both.

Documentation: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.11.x/google-pubsub-component.html#_query_parameters_13_parameters